# Data from last Index tab in Oracle SQL Developer for JDBC

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My Question is , is there a way to get all the Data displayd in the last tab "SQL" that is displayed in the Oracla SQL Developer.
My purpose is to write a code that drops all tables and recreates them as they were.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odfAa.png)

Comment: That tab shows a reconstructed ddl statement for your table. The best way to get that is just look it up in your source control system (e.g. git).  If you do not have source control (same on you) then just copy/paste that tab. You can also just get that from data dictionary (Start with `all_tab_columns`).  But *what is the point* drop and recreate **accomplishes nothing**.  Unless the point is to just erase the data nonrecoverable in which use truncate as @ArthurKlezovich suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My purpose is to write a code that drops all tables and recreates them as they were.

If you are working with Oracle you can use the `TRUNCATE TABLE`, which just removes all the data from the tables. Here's a [guide](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-truncate-table/) on how to use it.

You do in essence like this ...

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name
CASCADE;
```

Does this solve your problem ?